# [Leetcode]448. Find All Numbers Disappeared in an Array

Tags: python-2.7

[problem link from leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-all-numbers-disappeared-in-an-array/)

I came up with two solutions wrote in Python but did not pass and do not know why.

> Given an array of integers where 1 ≤ a[i] ≤ n (n = size of array),
>   some elements appear twice and others appear once.
>
> Find all the elements of [1, n] inclusive that do not appear in this
>   array.

Here is my first solution:

```
class Solution(object):
  def findDisappearedNumbers(self, nums):
     nums=sorted(list(set(nums)))
     for x in range(1, nums[-1] + 1):
       if x in nums:
         nums.remove(x)
       else:
         nums.append(x)
     return nums
```

the result is  " Runtime Error Message: Line 4: IndexError: list index out of range". But I did not get it.

The second solution:

```
return [x for x in range(1, len(nums) + 1) if x not in nums]
```

The result is "Time Limit Exceeded",still,confused.

Both solutions works okay in my Pycharm with python 2.7.11.Maybe there are some test cases my solutions did not pass but I can not find it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your first solution will fail if the test input is an empty list as num[-1] would give an index out of bound.
Your second solution will be slow as it has to iterate through the list. Would the below solution work? Set operations are optimised. But is the space complexity ok for you?

> ```
>     ret = set(range(1, len(nums)+1))
>     ret = ret - set(nums)
>     return list(ret)
> ```

Comment: "if x not in nums" takes too much time, my final solution "return list(set(range(1, len(nums) + 1)) - set(nums))" works out and basiclly the same as ur solution, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to use xrange instead of range as this uses less space when the value of nums is very large. Also, you are trying to iterate as well as delete/append a value at the same time in the same array. This is most likely the reason why you are getting the error.

Also, removing a value in the list (if it is not at the end) takes a lot of time because all other elements before it need to moved.

Answer (score 0):

From the first solution: **DO NOT** modify the list you are iterating. Always brings problems. Better copy the list and modify the list!

```
class Solution(object):
    def findDisappearedNumbers(self, nums):
        nums=sorted(list(set(nums)))
        nums_copy = nums.copy(nums)
        for x in range(1, nums[-1] + 1):
            if x in nums:
                nums_copy.remove(x)
            else:
                 nums_copy.append(x)
        return nums_copy
```

On the other hand, if `num` is very large (has many elemente)`range` can bring problems because it creates the list first (and VERY large lists occupy a LOT of memory). For me cases it is better to [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) than to return a generator.
This does not happen in python3, where the default [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#range) returns a generator.

Comment: yeah,u r right! thanks!,shouldn't manipulate the list while iterating,especially change the len of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nums = set(nums)` which will sort and remove all the duplicates. Then you can run a loop to append all the numbers not present in `nums` to output array.

Comment: A `set` doesn't sort the elements. Quite the opposite actually, a set is a random data structure